# Why does 4-thiouracil labelling to map RNA-binding proteins cause a T-C change?

Tags: molecular-biology, molecular-genetics, rna, purification

I am now reading [a paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22681889) about the purification and identification of mRNAs and its RNA binding proteins by using UV crosslinking and immunoprecipitation. I came upon this sentence which puzzled me

> Up to 28% of all uridines present in 3' UTRs showed diagnostic T-C
>   changes in the protein occupancy profiling sequence reads. This number
>   is reasonably high, considering observations that typically only one
>   of a few uridines in RNA binding sites when substituted by 4SU,
>   crosslinks to proteins.

What I do not understand is why does 4-thiouracil (4SU) labelling in the cell show T-C changes. Would the uracil-adenine base pairing not be affected?

How does the 4SU labelling really work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The technique used in that paper is called PAR-CLIP (Photoactivatable Ribonucleoside-Enhanced Crosslinking and Immunoprecipitation; see [Ascano et al., 2012](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3711140/) and [Spitzer et al, 2014](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24581442)). This technique involves substituting uridine (`U`) with 4-thiouridine (`4SU`) or substituting guanosine (`G`) with 6-thioguanosine (`6SG`). The rationale behind using these modified bases is that they improve the efficiency of RNA-protein crosslinking. Moreover, PAR-CLIP uses 365nm UV instead of the 254nm UV used in the conventional crosslinking. However, the crosslinking process causes the loss of the sulphur atom causing the `U` to be read as `C` during reverse transcription. Likewise, `6SG` gets read as `A`.

> [image]
>   <sub>[Ascano et al., 2012](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3711140/)</sub>